# WebView showing images from local cache

Tags: android

I have to show some HTML content in WebView which has both images from URL's over the internet and images from the local phone cache. The src tag of the img has values like the following:

file:///data/data/com.Domain.MyApp/cache/example.jpg

but WebView renders no image. I am sure that the path is correct and that file exists. What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `src` attributes of `img` tags like in this example:

```
/data/data/com.Domain.MyApp/cache/example.jpg
```

Save the HTML content as an HTML file into the same folder with the images (cache directory in the current problem).

Finally load the html file like this:

```
mDescriptionWeb.loadUrl("file://" + this.getCacheDir() + "/" + "current.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `cache` directory is not really a safe place to store things. Have you already considered the option to use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`?

My app download the contextual help from internet, save all files in `getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/help"` and open it from a `WebView` without any problem.

Look at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29

Give it a try...

Another option is to use Assets, look at 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Comment: In what terms it would be safer? If you are considering that cache directory could be cleaned automatically by the system, then it would be not a problem in my application.

Comment: are you trying to open the image directly or just a .html file with a <img>?

Comment: I think it could be a contextual problem. Just try to write the html file in the same directory with a <img> using a relative path. In your case just src="example.jpg" and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I solved problem by saving html file into the same directory.

Comment: Good! You confirm it's a contextual issue.